# for_each and transform

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, lambda

```
for_each(ivec.begin(),ivec.end(),
        []( int& a)->void{ a = a < 0 ? -a : a; 
    });

transform(ivec.begin(),ivec.end(),ivec.begin(),
        [](int a){return a < 0 ? -a : a;
    });
```

I am currently learning lambdas and I am curious how the two implementations, that I have posted above, differ?

Comment: The second instantly tells you something is being transformed, rather than looped through.

Comment: `->void` is unnecessary, and note that in C++ there's no implicit `return` of the value of the last expression-statement of a function.

Comment: Second one has 2 identical iterators. Your compiler will most likely notice it and only use one, so no perf difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This first version:

```
for_each(ivec.begin(),ivec.end(),
      []( int& a)->void{ a = a < 0 ? -a : a; 
});
```

works by calling the lambda function

```
 []( int& a)->void{ a = a < 0 ? -a : a; }
```

once for every element in the range, passing in the elements in the range as arguments.  Accordingly, it updates the elements in-place by directly changing their values.

This second version:

```
transform(ivec.begin(),ivec.end(),ivec.begin(),
    [](int a){return a < 0 ? -a : a;
});
```

works by applying the lambda function

```
[](int a){return a < 0 ? -a : a;}
```

to each of the elements in the range `ivec.begin()` to `ivec.end()`, generating a series of values, and then writing those values back to the range starting at `ivec.begin()`.  This means that it overwrites the original contents of the range with the range of values produced by applying the function to each array element, so the elements are overwritten rather than modified in-place.  The net effect is the same as the original `for_each`, though.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

The two implementations you show do not differ logically (assuming you get the first version right by adding a return). The first one modifies elements in place while the last one overwrites its elements with new values.

The biggest difference I see, with `transform` you just can pass `abs` instead of a lambda that reimplements it.

Comment: +1 for the additional perk: `transform` works much better with pre-existing functions when you want to change the elements.

Comment: `abs` is overloaded and you would have to `static_cast` it to the type of the desired overload, which quite a pain.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: and it gets even worse than that when you consider ADL and UDTs... if only we had a high level `abs` object that would perform `abs` on whatever you send its way!

Comment: @K-ballo Not sure what you mean; `static_cast` is the alpha and omega of resolving an overload to a pointer. You can create exactly such an object as `namespace impl { using std::abs; struct my_abs { template< typename ... args > auto operator() ( args && ... a ) -> decltype( abs( std::forward< args >( args ) ... ) ) { return abs( std::forward< args >( args ) ... ); } }; } typedef impl::my_abs abs;`. (Obviously overkill, but just giving the boilerplate.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Indeed that's what I meant...it would be much easier to work at that higher level!

Answer (score 4):

`transform` is what would, in a functional language, be called `map`. That is, it applies a function to every element in the input range, and stores the output into an output range. (So it is generally intended to not modify the inputs, and instead store a range of outputs)

`for_each` simply discards the return value from the applied function (so it might modify the inputs).

That's the main difference. They are similar, but designed for different purposes.